# Java Installation and Environment variable in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Java in Ubuntu 14.04. I had follow a guide (that was sent to me for a work for my thesis) and this is what I made:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Now I have to change the environment variable and, according to the guide, this is the few steps remaining:

- `sudo update-alternatives --config java` for get the environmnet variable path
- `$JAVA_HOME: sudo nano /etc/environment`
- `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`
- `source /etc/environment`

the problem is that I'm not sure where I have to write "JAVA_HOME: bla bla". In the Ubuntu shell? And, at the end, `source /etc/environment` doesn't work.

Comment: You should also set your `PATH` variable as well. Check the `profile` file of your shell

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in your `~/.bashrc` file, probably the end of the file is the best place:

```
vi ~/.bashrc         # open the file and add the value
source ~/.bashrc     # source it
echo $JFHOME         # make sure it changed
```

Then, you may need to add this path into `$PATH`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: when you write "add the value" you means only `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` (obviously at the end of the file)?

Comment: @Carlo check if `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns what you inserted.

Answer (score 0):

- vim /etc/profile
- modify file ,add the two lines

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

- source /etc/profile

make sure all the above has been done
then run "java -version" see if it works or not.